# Recyclerview child items width

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

How do I get width of all child items?

I put these codes inside **onCreateViewHolder**

```
viewholder.textView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {

            viewholder.textView.getWidth();
            Log.e("TAG", "onGlobalLayout: " + viewholder.textView.getWidth());

        }
    });
```

And then when I debug my app, there are a lot width values come out. How to get all childs width(included invisible childs) in the correct way?

Answer (score 0):

> And then when I debug my app, there are a lot width values come out. How to get all childs width(included invisible childs) in the correct way?

First, you cannot get the width of children, that are invisible (I assume you mean that are off screen boundaries), because they haven't been created.

> a lot width values come out

Second, you'd better unregister listener as soon as you're done with it:

```
viewholder.textView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        viewholder.textView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalFocusChangeListener(this);

        viewholder.textView.getWidth();
        Log.e("TAG", "onGlobalLayout: " + viewholder.textView.getWidth());

    }
});
```

Comment: Alright. What if I have 10 items and the recyclerview is selected on the first item. How can I scroll to the last item since from 7th item afterwards are invisible?

Comment: @WeiLong, `layoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(10, 0)`

Comment: it is not working, and it can only scroll forward only

Comment: Or is there anyway to search the target item, and make select to it. Without any scroll animation is fine.

Comment: @WeiLong, find the corresponding item's position in your `List` and then scroll to that item `linearLayoutManager.scrollToPosition(desiredindex)`

Comment: It is not working too, the invisible items wont be selected